# missing parenthesis in jquery event in xhtml page jsf2 application

Tags: jquery, events, parentheses

I tried to use this jquery code to validate my inputs :

```
$(".maqte , .monpu").on("keypress", function(){
         if (( (event.which != 46) || ($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) ) &amp;&amp; ( (event.which -lt 48) || (event.which -gt 57) ) {
                event.preventDefault();
              }
        });
```

but I have always this error in console of browser and the event is not launched  :

in chrome : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

in firefox :

```
SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical
```

I don't see which is this missing parenthesis

****************************EDIT
always the same error :

```
$(".maqte , .monpu").on("keypress", function(){
        if (( (event.which != 46) || ($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) ) &amp;&amp;
                   ((event.which -lt 48) || (event.which -gt 57) )){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        });
```

new code above

Answer (score 0):

you missing `)` at the end.

```
if (( (event.which != 46) || ($(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) ) &&
   ((event.which -lt 48) || (event.which -gt 57) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it got something to do with `-lt` and `-gt`. Try this instead:

```
if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: with `&&` I have : `The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.` and with `<` `>` I have this error `The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup`